# Excel ODBC Access Driver could not find file - looking for .mdb instead of .accdb

Tags: excel, ms-access, connection-string

I had an old .mdb database that was converted to .accdb last month.  At that time, I changed the Connection String to look at the .accdb instead - and it worked.  This month, when I went to refresh my Excel report, it gave me an error stating "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file 'file path/file name.MDB'.

Here is the connection string I have set up:
DBQ=H:\ZVDept\CorpOps-FieldOps Processing\Contract Certainty\All Sates Database\All States CC.accdb;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;

Why would Excel be looking for a .mdb file when I have the connection string set to .accdb?  I'm looking to connect an Excel 2010 report to an Access 2010 database.

I tried the process of using Microsoft Query instead, but this one report uses a handful of connections - and it bombed out when I tried setting up a second one, so I'd rather try to leave it using the Connection String method, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: nevermind - I found the issue.  I had an sql query written below it.  It did not have the .mdb at the end of the file path - but it seems like Excel was assuming it was .mdb.  By adding the .accdb to the end of the file path in the sql, it started working.

Comment: You should post your comment above as an *answer* and accept it. (Yes it is perfectly acceptable - and even encouraged - to answer your own question here)